# xcache.so issue on MAMP since Mavericks upgrade

Tags: php, mamp, drush, xcache, osx-mavericks

After updating to OSX 10.9 Mavericks, MAMP stopped to work with Xcache for some reason.

```
$ drush status
```

> Failed loading /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xcache.so:  dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xcache.so, 9): image not found
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imap.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imap.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'allow_call_time_pass_reference' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0

I tried to add the PATH to `.bash_profile` for `php5.4.19` but `drush` continues to look for 5.3.20

Comment: I created a symbolic link and I disabled the Xcache extension on the MAMP UI but I still find an issue:$ drush
XCache requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is newer.
Contact mOo at http://xcache.lighttpd.net for a later version of XCache.

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imap: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: If you run `$ which php` what does it say?

Comment: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php

Comment: maybe you need to set `DRUSH_PHP` to your preferred php version? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44967/drush-fails-to-detect-php-version-correctly

Comment: look if the /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/ is existing path. may be there is another directory name, I have solved the issue by moving the extensions files into the right folder.